# Suspected Perl buffering issue

Tags: perl, buffering

I think I'm having a Perl buffering issue since I need to read and parse big text files (created by myself in previous lines of the code) to finally print things in another file.

At some point, after reading a file with 90,855 lines and some other of the second file, the script is not reading a line of the file completely.

I have counted the number of characters read until this happens: 233,467, and therefore tried to flush the buffer and sleep before reading the next line of the file. It doesn't work.

Any suggestions, please?

Here is my code:

```
foreach $i (@files) {

    my $buff = 0;

    print "Analyzing $i\n";
    sleep(1);
    $program = $1 if $i =~ /(\w+)_SITES/;

    open(FIL, $i) or die "$!: $i\n";
    while (<FIL>) {

        $buff += length($_);
        if ($buff >= 230000) {  #FLUSH THE BUFFER, NOT WORKING!!!
            $buff = 0;
            sleep(1);
            select((select(FIL), $| = 1)[0]);
        }

        undef($a);
        unless ($. == 1) {
            if ($o == 0) {
                if (/^\d+\t(\S+)\t(\S+)\t(\d+)\t(\d+)\t(\S+)\t(\S+)\t(.*)/) {
                    $mirna  = $1;
                    $target = $2;
                    $start  = $3;
                    $end    = $4;
                    $site   = $5;
                    $comp_p = $6;
                    $a      = $7;
                    $j      = "${mirna}_${target}_${start}_$end";
                    $site_nu{$j} = "$mirna\t$target\t$start\t$end\t$site\t$comp_p";    # Store each site in a hash
                }
                else {   #DIES HERE!!!
                  die "$buff characters, in line $.:$_\n"
                }
            }
            else {
                if (/^\d+\t(\S+)\t(\S+)\t(\d+)\t(\d+)\t(\S+)\t(.*)/) {
                    $mirna       = $1;
                    $target      = $2;
                    $start       = $3;
                    $end         = $4;
                    $site        = $5;
                    $a           = $6;
                    $j           = "${mirna}_${target}_${start}_$end";
                    $site_nu{$j} = "$mirna\t$target\t$start\t$end\t$site";    # Store each site in a hash
                }
            }
```

It dies at the "DIES HERE!!" die, after reading 3,413 characters of the second file.

It happens because the regex doesn't work since only half of the line is in $_.

Comment: Is this script single threaded?

Comment: The variable `$|` controls the automatic flushing of *output files* after every `print` statement. It has no effect on input files, and flushing of an input file is meaningless.

Comment: If you are trying to read a tab separated file, you might take a look at [`Text::CSV`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text%3A%3ACSV). You should also add `use strict; use warnings;` to this script and fix the errors/warnings. Then rewrite the code to reduce the scope of all variables to the smallest possible, using the `my` keyword.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is almost certainly because the data isn't in your file to be read.

You say that the file is produced from an earlier part of your code. I suspect you have a buffering issue *there* instead. Once your code has finished writing the file, use `close` to flush the remaining data to the file and it is my guess that all will be well.

You should check the success status of your `close` call, like this

```
close FILEHANDLE or die "Unable to close temporary file: $!";
```

Aside from this, the wisdom of using a temporary file for such a small ampount of data instead of simply keeping it all in memory is questionable. In addition:

- You must *always* `use strict` and `use warnings` and declare all variables using `my` as close as possible to their first point of use. Unless you have chosen to declare everything at the top of your program (a very bad idea) you haven't done this
- Your choice of variable names is erratic. `$i` for a file name? And `$o` for - erm - something? `$buff` would be fine except that it is the *size* of a notional buffre instead of the buffer istelf
- You should use lexical filehandles with the three-parameter form of `open`: `open my $fil, '<', $i or die "$!: $i";`
- If you were using `$|` correctly, it is neater and more readable to use `FILE->autoflush` instead of the trick of swapping the selected filehandle and setting `$|`. To do this you need `use IO::Handle` at the start of your code, unless you are running Perl 5 version 14 or later which loads `IO::File` (and hence `IO::Handle`) on demand
- I think a simple `split /\t/` would be better than the regex you are using. It also looks like you would be better off with a hash of arrays for `%site_nu` like this `$site_nu{$j} = [$mirna, $target, $start, $end, $site, $comp_p]`
- Putting a newline at the end of a `die` string stops perl from displaying information on the source and data files and line numbers, which would probably be useful while you are debugging
- You would be doing yourself, and those people you ask for help, a favour by formatting your source code nicely. Without proper indenting it is very hard to tell where code blocks begin and end

Comment: Thanks for the comments, guys. Yes I use strict and use warnings, declare variables with my and successfully close all files after finished printing. I have checked and the data is indeed in the files to be read. I'll try all the other suggestions and I'll get back to you. Thank you so much.

Comment: Hi all. In the end, I flushed the output filehandle I was using, before start parsing the files and problem solved. Thank you all so much for the help.

Comment: @dannyjmh: Then you cannot have been closing it correctly. It is better to close the file than to flush it. You must also be declaring your variables in a big block at the start of the program, which is not a good idea.